# Translate Ant Design Pro Table default table's default operation

Tags: ant-design-pro

Is there any way to translate Ant Design Pro table's default operation text to English. I am using Umi default components

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are default translations for Ant Design Pro Table's operations. You will need to import them and use it with your table. The below example imports the `IntlProvider` and `enUSIntl` default translation.

** You can find the available default translations located at 
`node_modules/@ant-design/pro-table/lib/component/intlContext/index.d.ts`

```js
import ProTable, { ProColumns, IntlProvider, enUSIntl } from '@ant-design/pro-table';

const ExampleList: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <PageHeaderWrapper>
      <ProTable<TableListItem>
        headerTitle="Example List"
        actionRef={actionRef}
        rowKey="key"
        ...
      />
      ...
    </PageHeaderWrapper>
  )
}

export default () => (
  <IntlProvider value={enUSIntl}>
    <TableList />
  </IntlProvider>
)
```

[image]

You should see your Ant Design Pro Table's operations and tooltips translated in the imported language.

Hope that helps!